# How to fix Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

\views\index.ejs:37

```
35|
36| <!-- Offers Section --> >> 
37| <%- include("inc/content/offers") -%> 
38| <!-- End Offers Section --> 
39| 
40| <!-- Menu Section -->
```

C:\Users\Marcos\Desktop\projeto\restaurante\views\inc\content\offers.ejs:10

```
 8| 
 9| <div class="row"> >> 
10| <% menus.forEach((row)=>{%> 
11| <div class="col-sm-4"> 
12| <div class="item"> 
13| <div class="discount"> Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
```

\views\index.ejs:37

```
    35| 
    36|             <!-- Offers Section -->
 >> 37|             <%- include("inc/content/offers") -%>
    38|             <!-- End Offers Section -->
    39| 
    40|             <!-- Menu Section -->
```

\views\inc\content\offers.ejs:10

```
     8| 
     9|             <div class="row">
 >> 10|                 <% menus.forEach((row)=>{%>
    11|                 <div class="col-sm-4">
    12|                     <div class="item">
    13|                         <div class="discount">
```

Comment: Please post your node.js code. Are you using express? We need to see your route to check what you're passing to the view

Answer (score 0):

Check wether variable "menus" isset or not

Answer (score 0):

The error says "menus" is empty. 
I'm not sure about the technologies that you are using. But it seems that the html file is rendering before the time that you fill "menus" variable.

I think you need to fill "menus" before HTML rendering. 
I suggest you fill the variable in "constructor" life cycle hook and see if it helps you to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that menus is an enumerable, 
if it is an array make sure you run your loop like this
     `<% menus.to_a.forEach((row)=>{%>`